# I can't access a video after download it in android

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a code to download a video from my server and save it in the sd card. I use this code:

```
String videoURL = "http://www.myapp.com" + key + "/"+key+".avi";
    String PATHSdcard = getSDFile();

    try {
        //set the download URL, a url that points to a file on the internet
        //this is the file to be downloaded
        URL url = new URL(videoURL);

        //create the new connection
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        //set up some things on the connection
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        //and connect!
        urlConnection.connect();

        //set the path where we want to save the file
        //in this case, going to save it on the root directory of the
        //sd card.
        File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        //create a new file, specifying the path, and the filename
        //which we want to save the file as.
        File file = new File(PATHSdcard,key+".avi");

        //this will be used to write the downloaded data into the file we created
        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

        //this will be used in reading the data from the internet
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        //create a buffer...
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferLength = 0; //used to store a temporary size of the buffer

        //now, read through the input buffer and write the contents to the file
        while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                //add the data in the buffer to the file in the file output stream (the file on the sd card
                fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
        }
        //close the output stream when done
        fileOutput.flush();
        fileOutput.close();
        sendBroadcast (
                new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                    Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()))
            );

    //catch some possible errors...
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I download it correctly, but I can't play the video after downloaded it.

If I close my application and open again, the video works fine. Any solution?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have any errors while you try to play this video?

Comment: I get this error
Failed to open file '/storage/emulated/0/MyAppFolder/28499.avi'. (Permission denied)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have the correct permissions to write to the file. In your manifest file, include this line

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />.
```

UPDATED:
I am not sure what problem in your code, but can you try my code, maybe it will work:

```
public void DownloadFromUrl(String DownloadUrl, String fileName) {

try {
           File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();               

           File dir = new File (root.getAbsolutePath() + "/your_downloads");
           if(dir.exists()==false) {
                dir.mkdirs();
           }

           URL url = new URL(DownloadUrl); //you can write here any link
           File file = new File(dir, fileName);

           /* Open a connection to that URL. */
           URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();

           /*
            * Define InputStreams to read from the URLConnection.
            */
           InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
           BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

           /*
            * Read bytes to the Buffer until there is nothing more to read(-1).
            */
           ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(5000);
           int current = 0;
           while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
              baf.append((byte) current);
           }


           /* Convert the Bytes read to a String. */
           FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
           fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
           fos.flush();
           fos.close();

   } catch (IOException e) {
       Log.d("DownloadManager", "Error: " + e);
   }

}
```

Comment: I have this permissions
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS" />

This is not the problem, because when i close and open again, it works
Thanks

Comment: can you open this file in other application(not in yours) ?

Comment: No
I think that is a problem closing the file.
If i close the application, or wait a minute, work with all applications.